# Как установить значение элемента без Id, и name

Tags: javascript, html

Данное поле предназначено для ввода даты, нужно его заполнить в JavaScript функции
[image: Разметка]

```html
<div class="dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-input-container">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false">
            <div data-dx_placeholder="" class="dx-placeholder">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
            <div>

            </div>
            <div class="dx-button-normal dx-button-mode-contained dx-widget dx-dropdowneditor-button" role="button" aria-label="Select">
                <div class="dx-button-content">
                    <div class="dx-dropdowneditor-icon">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Заполнить чем? Текущим числом? Полученными данными, хаотичными данными, чем? Покажите как пробовали сделать сами?

Comment: Заполнить нужно текущей датой, делал так: (function(){ var obj = document.getElementByClassName('dx-texteditor-input')[1];obj.value = '18.02.2020';obj.setAttribute('val', obj.value);obj.focus();$(document.activeElement).trigger("change"); })()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
    window.onload = function () {
        var options = {
            year: 'numeric',
            month: 'numeric',
            day: 'numeric',
            timezone: 'UTC'
        };
        var date = new Date().toLocaleString("ru", options);
        var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('dx-texteditor-input');
        elem[0].value = date;
    }
```

```html
<div class="dx-dropdowneditor-input-wrapper">
    <input type="hidden" value="">
    <div class="dx-texteditor-container">
        <div class="dx-texteditor-input-container">
            <input autocomplete="off" class="dx-texteditor-input" aria-haspopup="true" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" role="combobox" aria-expanded="false">
            <div data-dx_placeholder="" class="dx-placeholder">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dx-texteditor-buttons-container">
            <div>

            </div>
            <div class="dx-button-normal dx-button-mode-contained dx-widget dx-dropdowneditor-button" role="button" aria-label="Select">
                <div class="dx-button-content">
                    <div class="dx-dropdowneditor-icon">

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, .................